# is there a way to check directory exists when similar filename exits?

Tags: bash, shell, glob

I have a directory and a file with similar name. i.e. filename --> test_16.4 and directoryName --> test_16.43

```
if [ -d test_* ]; then
   echo " directory exists!!!"
else
   echo "directory doesn't exists!!!"
fi
```

This returns "directory doesn't exists!!!" as it checks the condition with filename. how can i make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `*` with `*/` to get only directories.

For a quick test see output of:

```
echo test_*
echo test_*/
```